# Does whiskey go bad by freezing?

Tags: storage-method, whiskey

This question does not have to do with home brewing but I figured someone here would be able to answer.

- Does scotch whiskey go bad if kept in standard home freezers for a few days?
- Does it also matter that the air-tight seal has been broken? In other words for opened bottles.

It does seem to bubble very slightly when poured out but tastes fine. Just wondering if there is a big 'don't do that' attached to this.

Comment: I would be surprised if your whiskey freezes. I have stored vodka in the freezer for months, that's normal practice if you want ice-cold vodka always available, and it stays liquid, even standard 37.5° vodka. Of course, the vodka doesn't have any subtle flavors likely to change, so I can't say that your whiskey's quality won't suffer (although it is unlikely).

Comment: It does not freeze. But as soon as the cap is removed it starts getting murky in color similar to how water crystallizes when very cold and exposed to air.

Comment: I'm just curious. Why would you want to freeze it?

Comment: To avoid using ice which doesn't agree with me.

Comment: Raheel, what kind of whisky is it? Most whiskys naturally will get cloudy when cold, and of those most are chill-filtered to remove the murkiness (due to consumer preferences). Generally those that are not chill-filtered are more expensive because people that choose such are the more knowledgeable/demanding market who are willing to pay for the best.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised if the flavor profile changed when at -20 C, though how it would change as it warms up in the mouth/glass I have no idea. Would you be adding room temp water to your whisky?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting strong spirits in the freezer should not harm them. The solubility of air gases increases at low temperature, which is why you see bubbles as it warms up.

Drinks with a lower alcohol content will be affected in the freezer. There is potential to freeze water out of anything with an alcohol content of 28% or lower. Many people [use the freezer to increase the alcohol content of their home brew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_freezing#Alcoholic_beverages) in UK, by freezing water out of it - the alcohol stays in the liquid portion.

Comment: I thought as much. Since the color does turn a little opaque when exposed to air, I just wanted to make sure it doesn't become harmful.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, It goes bad. I stored my entire stock of liquor outside during an Ohio winter for about a week, just took the cap off my previously unopended bottle of Jack Daniels and soon as I took a shot it had a terrible spoiled taste, and i mean I have old no. 7 tatooed on my arm but I just cant drink anymore of it(and sadly its the big 1.75 ltr)

Comment: This goes against everything I know about both liquor and about storage. Can you perhaps support your answer beyond: "it happened once to me"

Comment: It's possible that he accidentally concentrated the alcohol in the non-frozen portion and that changed the taste?

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes the transition from warm to cold for whisky, rum and other spirits can cause the water to evaporate a bit making the level of alcohol more potent and the bottle less although you do not loose alcohol content. Just taste and density. Never cool off warm spirits.

Comment: ... can cause the water to evaporate *but not the alcohol*? Alcohol evaporates much faster than water. Please back this up with some data.

Comment: @JanDoggen worse: the transition _ from warm to cold_ will cause the water to evaporate??

Comment: I think he means 'freeze'.